# why does doctype change 'display:table-cell'' behaviour

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have made a form with inputs. The widths of these inputs are 100%, 75%, 50% and 25%, and I should be able to combine them to a row (so a 50/50, 25/25/25/25).

These inputs can't have fixed sizes, the div arround the wrapping form can be **any** width. The problem is that there are borders and paddings which are in pixels and CSS does not allow `width: 100%-10px;`.

The solution I've found was adding `display: table-cell` to a wrapping  and the div wrapping that `display: table`. Small example:

```
<div>
    <span class="Half"><input class="" value="Half"/></span>
    <span class="Half"><input class="" value="Half"/></span>
</div>
```

With my css this works .perfectly. If I add padding to the input, the padding just makes the width smaller.

The problem: When I add `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the padding makes the input overflow the span. No doctype=no problem, but I want to keep using it.

I've made an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/35SSR/

As you can see, there are no gaps between the inputs, and the inputs overflow the form. This is because jsFiddle also uses the doctype

Anyone got some ideas?

**Example** (I want the 'no doctype' looks in a 'with doctype' page, has to be crossbrowser):
[image: example image of problem]
<sub>(source: [lab35.nl](http://api.lab35.nl/doctype-problem.jpg))</sub>
.

Comment: just asking, do you use labels or not ? (just trying to understand why you're aiming to have only input boxes without labels)

Comment: Im not going for labels because in this case we use the placeholder attribute, adding a label would be double. Adding a label should work if I get the inputs to work (instead of the `span` wrapping the `input`, it would be wrapping the `label`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. In order to emulate quirks mode (ie the mode without a doctype) in standards mode, you need to include the `box-sizing:border-box` style. Note, if you want to support Firefox, you also need the prefixed version (`-moz-box-sizing`). Older webkit browser might also need a prefix.

   You can to apply this to the global selector so that it affects all elements or just to the `span` elements (since those are the ones that need it).

   The reason you need this is because the spans are set to percentage widths, that you want to add up to 100%. But in default behaviour in standards mode, borders, padding and margin are added outside of the box, so your 50% width actually becomes 50% plus and extra 5px for the border, etc. This is why it overflows off the side.

   The `border-box` setting switches it into a mode that works very similarly to how quirks mode worked, ie the borders etc are put *inside* the box, so that if you ask for a 50% wide box, it will be 50% wide, even when it has a border or padding.
2. The second point is that `display:table` and `display:table-cell` don't always work as expected unless you also have another layer of markup between them set as `display:table-row`. So if you want to continue using the table layout styles, you should add this.

   However your layout doesn't really lend itself to a table format anyway; it's a perfect example of where `float:left` should be used. I'm normally not a fan of floats, but this is one case where I would say to use it because it's pretty much exactly the use-case they had in mind when they invented them.

With those points in mind, I've completely rewritten your jsFiddle code using floats and box-sizing, and produced CSS code for you that looks exactly like your intended effect, without any changes to the HTML markup.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/35SSR/5/

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is perfect thanks. I made this the solution because you explained how border-box works (never know it changed the box-model). Also, the `span+span`, I love it. Im kinda puzzled as to why I never knew this one, but this is perfect in so many ways. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If you use *box-sizing: border-box;* for your inputs you can have width:100% and padding:10px;

Okay, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/cmex/35SSR/4/

I've added `-moz-` and `-webkit-` properties so it works now in Chrome 28, Firefox 22, IE (8-10), Safari 5.1.7(Win)

If you need to support earlier versions of IE you can use https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill
for support of box-sizing

Comment: Made no difference. If you could add it to my jsFiddle, just in case I do something wrong

Comment: Not really sure what it's showing you, but this is not the result im looking for at all. The inputs together should make 100%, please so my added image as example

Comment: My version in jsfiddle shows me exatly the same picture you provided as 'No Doctype'

Comment: But I want the 'with doctype' one. You must always define one, I kinda figured that would be clear. I'll update the question to clarify

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you expect to get? I want to say that my version (with doctype, it's provided by jsfiddle) looks exactly the same as yours without it. All inputs have expected width and position inside of form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34214/discussion-between-sergey-kochetov-and-martijn)

Comment: I can't chat right now. You are probally checking this in Chrome, IE and Firefox produce a weird result, with all inputs about their default widths (so allot of gaps and weird lines)
Edit: Crossbrowser is a MUST in my case.

Comment: @SergeyKochetov Martijn is trying to tell you that you can achieve the left state with a doctype if your inputs get the following CSS:

        `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */`
 `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */`
 `box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */`

Comment: @Serg, if you could add the webkit and moz-box to your reply, I'll mark it as solution. Still not 100% solution for me, but enough. Thanks both

Comment: @Martijn - you said this isn't a 100% solution, so please see my answer for an updated jsfiddle that does look 100% like your original screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i am solving this by using tables. It's easier to style with.

in HTML,

```
<fieldset>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input class="Full" value="Full"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input class="Half" value="Half"/></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input class="Half" value="Half"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="Quarter" value="Quarter"/></td>
            <td><input class="Quarter" value="Quarter"/></td>
            <td><input class="Quarter" value="Quarter"/></td>
            <td><input class="Quarter" value="Quarter"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="Quarter" value="Quarter"/></td>
            <td colspan="3"><input class="ThreeQuarter" value="ThreeQuarter"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input class="ThreeQuarter" value="ThreeQuarter"/></td>
            <td><input class="Quarter" value="Quarter"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

then in css, just a simple

```
table {
    width: 500px;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

required. then you get all in one fieldset box. [image: See example here]

Comment: yeah, but I'm trying not to use tables. We also have a 1/3 and 2/3 option, which gets really sloppy with colspans. Really trying not to have to do this